# Best way to connect Dell Precision 5520 laptop to Dell UltraSharp U2717D Monitor

Tags: laptop, hdmi, external-display, thunderbolt, usb-c

My Dell 5520 laptop has multiple display connection possibilities.

1. HDMI
2. Thunderbolt 3 / USB C
3. USB 3.0

My Dell U2717D has:

1. HDMI (MHL)
2. DisplayPort
3. Mini DisplayPort

I also have a Kensington SD3500v USB 3.0 Docking Station however, I believe the resolution of the U2717D (2560 x 1440) exceeds the 2048 x 1152 capability of the docking station.

What is the ideal cable to connect the laptop to the monitor?

1. USB C to Mini DisplayPort
2. USB C to DisplayPort
3. HDMI to HDMI
4. Some other cable or docking station

I tried connecting via HDMI but the text in certain apps in Windows 10 seems fuzzy. Is USB C a better way to connect? Would a docking station like the Dell TB16 have better text display?

Comment: Try each method and choose the one you like the best.

Comment: the hdmi you use is fine. I'd rather play with your scaling either from the windows settings and the one from your graphics card setting as well. Since you got the intel graphic card, verify your Intel control panel scaling settings there as well.

Comment: @Ramhound I was trying to avoid buying extra cables if one of them is the obvious choice.

Comment: Try adjusting Windows ClearType.